# How can I fix my php array?

Tags: php, arrays

so I have loop where it spits out each row of data from my database. Output show below

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => Saratoga [4] => test [5] => 7-2 [6] 
=> Red [7] => Bob [8] => Jill ) 
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => Saratoga [4] => test 2 [5] => 3-3 [6] 
 => White [7] => Bill [8] => Austin ) 
 Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => Saratoga [4] => test 3 [5] => 2-2 
 [6] => Blue [7] => Austin [8] => jill )
```

how do I combine this into one array?

code is down below on how I am doing my loop for my array

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `2018-08-20`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$rn = 1;
// output data of each row
   $aa = 1;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $a = array($aa,$row["RaceNumber"], $row["HorseNum"], $row["Track"], 
$row["HorseName"], $row["Odds"], $row["Color"], $row["JockeyName"], 
$row["TrainerName"] );

  for($x=0;$x < $a[1];$x++){
      $aa++;
  print_r($a);
 echo "<br/>";
    $rn++;

  }
}

  echo ' <button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button></form>';
echo "</table>";

} else {
echo "0 results";

}
```

Comment: Hello,  Please be a little more specific of what your desired output is to look like.

Comment: sort of like this where it just continues to add each row into the array. but only if the horse number is greater than or equal to the $aa row which has an increment of +1 of each iteration. 
    Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => Saratoga [4] => test [5] => 7-2 [6] 
    => Red [7] => Bob [8] => Jill  [9] => 2 [10] => 1 [11] => 2 [12] => Saratoga 
    [13] => test 2 [14] => 3-3 [16] => White [16] => Bill [17] => Austin [18] => 3 
    [19] => 1 [20] => 3 [21] => Saratoga [22] => test 3 [23] => 2-2 
     [24] => Blue [25] => Austin [26] => jill )

Comment: Is your table name `2018-08-20` or are you wanting all the info "WHERE" a date is equal to `2018-08-20`?

Comment: that is my table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. In the following code we are storing all arrays in `$all_data` array.

```
$all_data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $a = array($row["RaceNumber"], $row["HorseNum"], $row["Track"], 
    $row["HorseName"], $row["Odds"], $row["Color"], $row["JockeyName"], 
    $row["TrainerName"] );

    $all_data[] = $a;
}
print_r($all_data);
```

Comment: Thank you, things so simple like this go over my head and I overthink my code so much I never thought of it this way.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array containing the fields that you have coded in your loop, you should just code them into your query.  I'm not sure what you are doing with the `$aa` in your array, but you have it there so I'm including it in my last example.

**SQL APPROACH:**

Note: The `$aa` will be missing.

```
$sql = "SELECT 

  `RaceNumber`,
  `HorseNum`,
  `Track`,
  `HorseName`,
  `Odds`,
  `Color`,
  `JockeyName`,
  `TrainerName`

 FROM `2018-08-20`";

$results = $conn->query($sql);

print_r($results);
```

**YOUR CURRENT SETUP**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `2018-08-20`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  $rn = 1; //What are these for???
  $aa = 1;

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $a[] = array(

            $aa, 
            $row["RaceNumber"],
            $row["HorseNum"],
            $row["Track"], 
            $row["HorseName"],
            $row["Odds"],
            $row["Color"],
            $row["JockeyName"], 
            $row["TrainerName"]

           );

  }

  print_r($a);

  echo ' <button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button></form>';
  echo "</table>";

} else {

echo "0 results";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
$all_data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $all_data[] = $row;
}

var_dump($all_data);
```

As the $row will be in array format , you can directly add that to array

you can read more on 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php